# RequireJS + Waypoints : Object [object Object] has no method 'waypoint'

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jquery-waypoints

I can't use waypoints with RequireJS although everything looks good.
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/7nGzj/

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "theme/PereOlive/js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app":"../app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "waypoints.min": ["jquery"]
    }
});
requirejs(["app/common"]);
```

**common.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    "waypoints.min",
], function () {
    $(function () {
        console.log($.waypoints);
        $('#loading').waypoint(function (direction) {
            // do stuff
        });
    });
});
```

I even shimed it to be sure jQuery is properly loaded but it doesn't work.
My other libraries works like they should (responsiveslides, flexslider, hoverintent, smoothscroll, ..).

- jQuery V1.10.2
- Waypoints V2.0.3
- RequireJS V2.1.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dependencies which are AMD-compliant (and Waypoints is) should be `require`d via their registered module name. The easiest (only?) way to find out what that name is is to look into the lib's source code:

```
// (...)
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  return define('waypoints', ['jquery'], function($) {
    return factory($, root);
  });
} // (...)
```

It's "`waypoints`"!

Since the library is AMD-compatibile, you don't need a shim but you'll need to define the path to it (since the file name can be different than the AMD module name):

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "theme/PereOlive/js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "waypoints": "path/to/waypoints.min"
    }
});
```

After doing that, you'll need to change you `require` call:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "waypoints" // this is the AMD module name
]
```

---

Fixed your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jVdSk/2/