# RequireJS and scrollReveal.js seems not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dependencies, requirejs

I am using RequireJS for my Dependency-Management and scrollReveal.js ([github-repo](https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js)) for creating nice effects.

But scrollReveal, for some reasons seems not to work.

Here is some code:

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        'sreveal': "assets/vendor/scrollreveal.min"
    }
    ...
});
```

And in my common.js, I use it like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'sreveal'
     ], function ($, sreveal) {
     ...
 });
```

Usally, this plugin works by setting up a data-attribute for the elements which should reveal.
By using this script without RequireJS, it work's perfectly.

I also tried to init scrollReveal like this:

```
window.scrollReveal = new scrollReveal();
```

No result.

Hope you have any experience with this.

Comment: Are you able to load the scrollReveal.js lib using RequireJS?

Comment: Yes, I am. All other libs I load via RequireJs are working perfectly except of scrollReveal

Comment: Check whether you are invoking the scrollReveal.js only after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I am using the domReady-plugin

Comment: Since scrollReveal is a non-AMD, have you specified shim configuration?

Answer (score 1):

ScrollReveal is AMD-compatibile but you need to configure `paths` element correctly to link its name (which is "`scrollReveal`") with script's location on your filesystem:

```
require.config({
    // ...
    paths: {
        'scrollReveal': 'assets/vendor/scrollreveal.min'
    }
    // ...
});
```

And then require use it via:

```
define(['jquery', 'scrollReveal'], function ($, sreveal) {
      console.log('ScrollReveal loaded?', sreveal);
 });
```

---

You could have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322107/1240557), I tried to explain how to deal with this kind of problems in practice.